# Google Apps Script. How do i specify my spreadsheet ID to "Sheet 3"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My function should only get information from one sheet within the spreadsheet document. I tried putting the default Spreadsheet ID + gid but it is not working. What do i need to do?

```
var pVorname = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1MzLZ.....#gid=594...', 'B2:B100');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var pVorname = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('###spreadsheetId###', "'Sheet 3'!B2:B100");
```

- By this modification, the values are retrieved from the range of "B2:B100" in "Sheet 3". In this case, please use the sheet name and range as the A1Notation.
- `###spreadsheetId###` is the Spreadsheet ID. For example, when you had used `1MzLZ.....#gid=594...`, please modify to `1MzLZ.....` by removing `#gid=594...` as the Spreadsheet ID.
- From your title of `Google Apps Script. How do i specify my spreadsheet ID to "Sheet 3"?`, I used `Sheet 3` as the sheet name.

#### Note:

- If you are required to use the sheet ID, you can also use the following modified script.

  ```
    var sheetId = "0";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets().find(e => e.getSheetId() == sheetId);
    if (sheet) {
      var pVorname = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(), `'${sheet.getSheetName()}'!B2:B100`);
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)